# How to disable '^[[D' thing while typing in the console in Rust?

Tags: rust, terminal, console

I just started learning Rust recently. And I was creating a little program that accepts user input:

```
let mut text = String::new();
stdin().read_line(&mut text).expect("Failed to read line.");
```

But I can't use my arrows while typing:

```
helo World^[[D
```

As you can see, when I type arrows, this weird `^[[D` thing appears. How can I disable that?

**Update**

BTW, I can fix this issue in Python like this:

```
import readline

text = input("Input")
```

Comment: Huge can of worms.  Short answer: use a line editing library.  Long answer: drive yourself insane learning the arcane history of terminals and TTYs and keyboards and operating systems and how it's all patched together with 60 years of sticky tape and glue.

Comment: Are there any editing libraries you recommend?

Comment: [rustyline](https://crates.io/crates/rustyline) is pretty popular, but perhaps more fully featured/bloated than you require here.